# OnRenderSizeChanged overriden with reduced access error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am hosting a Win32 OpenGL window in WPF through a DLL. In the DLL when I try to override `OnRenderSizeChanged` from the base class `HwndHost` I get the error that it is being overridden with reduced access. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I am following these two tutorials [Creating OpenGL Windows in WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23736/Creating-OpenGL-Windows-in-WPF#HostingWin32APIWindows8) and [Walkthrough: Host a Win32 Control in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-win32-control-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). The latter is from Microsoft.

Here is my function:

```
virtual void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo^ sizeInfo) override
        {
            if (m_hDC == NULL || m_hRC == NULL)
                return;

            // Apply DPI correction
            // NOTE: sizeInfo->NewSize contains doubles, so we do the multiplication before
            // converting to int.
            int iHeight = (int)(sizeInfo->NewSize.Height * m_dScaleY);
            int iWidth = (int)(sizeInfo->NewSize.Width * m_dScaleX);

            if (iWidth == 0 || iHeight == 0)
                return;

            wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);
            glViewport(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0);
            // gluPerspective( 67.5, ((double)(iWidth) / (double)(iHeight)), 1.0, 500.0);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3252?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*A class that implements a virtual method from a base class or any method from an interface cannot reduce the access of that method.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3252?view=msvc-170)

Making the function public fixed it.

```
public:
        virtual void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo^ sizeInfo) override
```